# Can I send files created from bitmaps rather then files from assets folder through Content Provider?

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-contentprovider

I have assets folder with images in my project structure and I send them to other app through content provider. My task is to create files in runtime from imageviews (so and I cant put them to assets folder in runtime) and send them with content provider.

Content provider code:

```
...
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public AssetFileDescriptor openAssetFile(@NonNull Uri uri, @NonNull String mode) {
        final int matchCode = MATCHER.match(uri);
        if (matchCode == STICKERS_ASSET_CODE || matchCode == STICKER_PACK_TRAY_ICON_CODE) {
            return getImageAsset(uri);
        }
        return null;
    }

    private AssetFileDescriptor getImageAsset(Uri uri) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        AssetManager am = Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()).getAssets();
        final List<String> pathSegments = uri.getPathSegments();
        if (pathSegments.size() != 3) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("path segments should be 3, uri is: " + uri);
        }
        String fileName = pathSegments.get(pathSegments.size() - 1);
        final String identifier = pathSegments.get(pathSegments.size() - 2);
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(identifier)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("identifier is empty, uri: " + uri);
        }
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(fileName)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("file name is empty, uri: " + uri);
        }
        //making sure the file that is trying to be fetched is in the list of stickers.
        for (StickerPack stickerPack : getStickerPackList()) {
            if (identifier.equals(stickerPack.identifier)) {
                if (fileName.equals(stickerPack.trayImageFile)) {
                    return fetchFile(uri, am, fileName, identifier);
                } else {
                    for (Sticker sticker : stickerPack.getStickers()) {
                        if (fileName.equals(sticker.imageFileName)) {
                            return fetchFile(uri, am, fileName, identifier);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private AssetFileDescriptor fetchFile(@NonNull Uri uri, @NonNull AssetManager am, @NonNull String fileName, @NonNull String identifier) {
        try {
            return am.openFd(identifier + "/" + fileName);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(Objects.requireNonNull(getContext()).getPackageName(), "IOException when getting asset file, uri:" + uri, e);
            return null;
        }
    }
...
```

Comment: Write them to a file (e.g., in `getCacheDir()`) and use `FileProvider` to serve them.

Comment: Your biggest problem is that there's no promise that your app won't be kileld for resources, so bitmaps in memory may not stay in memory.  The best thing to do is write it to a file, although you may be able to do that when a URI is requested to prevent unnecessary file writes.